# i am try to create session but always session empty

Tags: php

**I want to try to make a session but always session Empty**.Use this code rate this product this link send an email open email and click link Active than code working session empty please help me...

```
<?php
    session_start();

     include("myhomeportal/setting/config.php"); 

    $conform = $_GET['conform'];

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM item_users where com_code='$conform'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    if ($row) {

        // now update `com_code`
        $sql = "UPDATE item_users SET com_code='active', user_type='user' WHERE com_code='$conform'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

        $inventory_id = $row['inventory_id'];

        $active = $row['com_code'];

         $_SESSION['sess_active'] = $active;

        header("Location: category.php?inventory_id=$inventory_id");
    } else {

        // confirm code not found, show error
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Verify with `var_dump(session_id());` that you work on the same session id. If this value is changing then you don't send the session id to the next page. Check with `var_dump($_COOKIE);` what cookie values you are sending from one page to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug first.
Echo this `$row['com_code'];` then  `$_SESSION['sess_active']`.

If they print something then go ahead.

Comment: $row['com_code']; then  $_SESSION['sess_active']. working fine same page echo data but header location not print.

Comment: You should declare the Session in every page, like: `session_start();` then try to echo `$_SESSION['sess_active']` did you declare to another page?

Comment: sir other page is not working session just simple test code

Comment: <h1>welcome <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['sess_active'];?> </h1>

Comment: Is that page is php?

Comment: yes sir i testing just header location domo.php and code is used <h1>welcome <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['sess_active'];?> </h1> but session empty

Comment: https://www.proyellowpage.com/category.php?inventory_id=4 check it link

Answer (score 0):

There ir an error in your test page.

"sir other page is not working session just simple test code – Pankaj"

Instead you are only testing, you must start the session always with session_start() in every .php you want to use session.

### Solving testing page.

```
"<h1>welcome <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['sess_active'];?> </h1> – Panka"
```

#### Note from w3schools:

The session_start() function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.

you are writting some html code before start the session, you should do that way:

```
<? php session_start(); ?>

<h1>welcome <?= $_SESSION['sess_active']; ?> </h1>
```

You can read more about this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: sir i using demo.php code is <?php session_start();?>
    <h1>welcome <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['sess_active'];?> </h1> but not working

Comment: thats not what i telled you, you are writting two times the sesion_start

Comment: sir session is not working any other page only working the same page ?

Comment: session works globally in your browser, no matter whitch page if you start the session with session_start at the very first

Comment: demo.php all content here, 
                <?php session_start();?>
    <h1>welcome <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['sess_active'];?> </h1>

Comment: i am try header location demo.php

Comment: is not like this:  <?php session_start();?> <h1>welcome <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['sess_active'];?> </h1>, is like this: <? php session_start(); ?>

<h1>welcome <?= $_SESSION['sess_active']; ?> </h1>